# How can I count how many keys have a certain value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary looking something like this:

```
d = {'f1': ['a','a','b','c'],
     'f2': ['b','c','d'],
     'f3': ['a','c','d']}
```

I want to get information about how many keys have a certain value. 
For example:  a:2, b:1, c:3... 
(And if value was in one key more than once, count only first one).
Is there a way to do it?
Everything I found was about comparing two dictionaries, but here I have one. 
I searched a lot but I haven't found solution for case like this. 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please give some actual input data and the full expected output. The count of `c` should be 1, no? See [ask] and [mre] for reference.

Comment: Or should the count of `b` be 2?

Comment: You might want to look into `set`s and `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @mariposard please don't hesitate to ask more questions to the given answers to your main question. It is important that you understand the answers rather using them without you understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Slow one liner:

```
>>> {k:sum(1 for l in d.values() if k in l) for k in set(sum(d.values(), []))}
{'a': 2, 'd': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best way but is this what you are looking for?

```
d = {'f1': ['a','a','b','c'],'f2': ['b','c','d'],'f3': ['a','c','d']}
certain_value = 'a'
counter = 0
for key, value in d.items():   
    if certain_value in value:
        counter += 1
    print("{0} has the {1} for {2} times.".format(key, certain_value, counter))
    counter = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful!

Comment: But I guess you are also looking for the total number of appearance of a certain_value, right?

Answer (score 2):

### Define a function `genMap` in your code, it will do the job

```py
d = {
  'f1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
  'f2': ['b', 'c', 'd'],
  'f3': ['a', 'c', 'd']
}

def genMap(obj):
  final_map = {}

  for key in obj:
    already_mapped = []
    for value in d[key]:
      if(value not in already_mapped):
        already_mapped.append(value)
        if(value not in final_map):
          final_map[value] = 0
        final_map[value] += 1
  return final_map

result = genMap(d)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{
  'a': 2,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 2
}
```